# FocusedRowChanged

Tags: c#

I use FocusedRowChanged event to pass data from another form.

```
    private void gridView7_FocusedRowChanged(object sender, FocusedRowChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        documents j = (documents)gridView7.GetRow(e.FocusedRowHandle);
        frmDocumentum doc = new frmDocumentum(Convert.ToInt32(j.document_id));
        doc.Show(); 
    }
```

My problem is that this function always runs when the application starts. How can I prevent that from running the function every time?

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to run this once, use a boolean variable:

```
bool bStartedOnce=false;

{
     if(!bStartedOnce)
     {
         ...
         bStartedOnce=true;
     }
}
```

Comment: I do not want to start only once, but it does not run on startup.